# Android Java: Exporting SQLite to CSV - no folder path or file created issue

Tags: android, sqlite, export-to-csv

i have been working on this for some days already. So far, as per other posts on this website and outside, I have added permissions and called method for permission check. However, I am stuck with exporting file. My method looks ok, as it says that export is successful. But, no file or folder created.
Something might be wrong with the path or create folder action? :(

Here is my latest code.

**1. Permissions added in manifest & CatalogActivity:**

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

**2. Upon button click  tryExporting(); is triggered.
Methods for permissions request additionally created in Catalog Activity:**

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {

        //export data to CSV using method in InventoryProvider via separate java class ExportDatabaseCSVTask
            case  R.id.export_to_csv:
                tryExporting();

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**3. ExportDatabaseCSVTask class:**

```
public class ExportDatabaseCSVTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

    SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    InventoryProvider iProvider;
    InventoryDbHelper mDbHelper;

    File file = null;
    boolean bool = false;


    public ExportDatabaseCSVTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        if (dialog == null) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setMessage("Downloading Files... Please Wait...");
        dialog.show();
        }


    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "/Inventory/");
        int result = 0;

        if (!exportDir.exists()) {
            Log.d("My App", "folder exist:" + exportDir.toString());
            result = 2;
        } else
            try {
                if (exportDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("My App", "folder created:" + exportDir.toString());
                    result = 1; // folder created
                } else {
                    Log.d("My App", "create folder fails:" + exportDir.toString());
                    result = 0; // creat folder fails
                }
            }catch (Exception ecp){
                ecp.printStackTrace();
            }


        file = new File(exportDir,"File.csv");
                try {
                    bool = file.createNewFile();
                    // prints
                    System.out.println("File created: "+bool);
                    if (!file.createNewFile()) {
                        Log.e("APP", "Couldn't create the file");
                        System.out.println("APP: File already exists");
                    }

                    CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                    database = this.mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                   database = this.mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                    Cursor curCSV = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM inventory", null); ---- ERROR HERE


                    csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
                    while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {
                        String arrStr[] = null;
                        String[] mySecondStringArray = new String[curCSV.getColumnNames().length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < curCSV.getColumnNames().length; i++) {
                            mySecondStringArray[i] = curCSV.getString(i);
                        }
                        csvWrite.writeNext(mySecondStringArray);
                    }
                   // csvWrite.flush(); ---> not sure about this one
                    csvWrite.close();
                    curCSV.close();
                    return true;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        return true;
    }



    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog != null) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) { dialog.dismiss();
             dialog = null;
            }
        }

       if (success) {
           Toast.makeText(context, "Export successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//ShareFile();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Export failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
```

Update - file is created, but its empty due to null pointer exception.
Tried to declare rawQuery static to resolve, but method in Provider is non-static, and making it static disables 'getContext().getContentResolver(),' from provider.
How to refer to provider query correctly?

**Updated Logcat:**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.example.android.app.data.InventoryProvider.exportQuery(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked with a different directory? Try Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/your_package_name/" Is there a reason why are you targeting Oreo?

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks a lot for the reply. Yes, i have tried previously and now getExternalStorageDirectory with various folders. It says folder exists /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packagename , but there is no folder in that location (although other apps package folders are there). You're right, removed tag for Oreo, same problem remains.

Comment: I think the next step would be to check with debug the code you actually export the csv file. I'm sure it will give you an exception, because as you mentioned it seems to work till that point

Comment: well, what do you mean if I actually export? There is no folder or file in the provided location, so nothing is exporting. Please clarify? Thank you!

Comment: I meant there is definitely a problem after you try to create the file and export the data to CSV file. In order to check what is the problem you should use debug and check if you get an exception after you create the CSV file.

Comment: I have added WRITE permissions, after the logcat showed that permission denied. Now, the file is created, but is empty. Something is wrong with cursor raw query.....Error exportQuery(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: You can add manually the permissions you need(just to verify the problem), long press the icon of your app, go to app info, click on permissions and Grant the write to storage permission and see if the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue:

1. Apart from adding **WRITE permission in the method**
   (previously, I had only READ permission in the method and both permissions in manifest);
2. also added the following before querying cursor (removed this, and declared SQLiteDatabase)

   ```
   SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
   ```

(previously, it was  `database = this.mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();`)

Now, the files saves nicely in the specified location.